# Chamar chave de um banco de dados para um usuário escolher em um formulário Php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "certificados");
?>
<form name="produto" method="post" action="">
 <label for="">Selecione um Nome de Autor</label>
 <select>
 <option>Selecione...</option>

 <?php while($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $prod["aut_nome"] ?>"</option>
 <?php } ?>
```

---

Porque este código não funciona não aparece os dados do banco de dados para escolher obrigado!!!

Comment: Você está dando comando de "certificados", acredito que seria ao menos `"SELECT * FROM certificados"`, veja em http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Também falta acertar a tag option  <option value="<?php echo $prod["aut_nome"] ?>"><?php echo $prod["aut_nome"] ?></option>

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","USUARIO","SENHA","DB");
$query = ("SELECT * FROM certificados");
$resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$query);
?>
<form name="produto" method="post" action="">
<label for="">Selecione um Nome de Autor</label>
<select>
<option>Selecione...</option>
<?php while($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_pedido)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $prod["aut_nome"] ?>"><?php echo $prod["aut_nome"] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: fiz teste no meu servidor e rodando redondo